# How can i set offset value to QElapsedTimer

Tags: c++, qt5

I want a particular action to happen after a certain period of time and I am using QElapsed timer for this.

```
  QElapsedTimer timer;

   timer.start();
//   timer.offSettime(2000); can i do like this
   if (m_state)
    if (timer.elapsed() > m_interval )
    {
        flip();
        timer.restart();
    }
```

I want for the first time this function to be executed always, irrespective of the variable m_interval.

For this is have another bool variable which is set to false once the function is executed.

Can we offset the elapsed time of timer so that first also it returns true or do we have any other way of doing this?

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understood your problem correct but isn't [QElapsedTimer::restart()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qelapsedtimer.html#restart) what you are looking for?

Comment: @Scheff  this function is in a loop and want this function always to be executed for the first time  irrrespective of  timer.elapsed() > m_interval this condition.

Comment: So i wanted to offset the clock so that if will pass the condition and than i  would be restarting the clock.

Comment: Currently i have a bool variable which tells me that the function is being executed for the first time.

Comment: Please, provide a [mcve] to make your intention clear. I don't get why you start the `QElapsedTimer` as long as you want to execute always. Why don't your call your function first unconditionally and then you start the `QElapsedTimer`?